# Significado "sacar la frisa" en un cuento de Bioy Casares

Tags: argentina

En "El caso de los viejitos voladores", de Bioy Casares, el protagonista termina diciendo "¿Usted sabe cómo le sacan la frisa al premiado?".

¿Alguien sabe qué significa esa expresión?
Según la RAE *frisa* es "pelusa" y en ese sentido quizás signifique sacar "envidia", porque este último aparece como un uso de pelusa y eso me parece más adecuado por contexto.

Answer (score 1):

Es una frase muy antigua y aparentemente usada sólo en Argentina. Traté de encontrar ejemplos de uso pero veo que sólo está en canciones populares.

La *frisa* es el pelo de algunas telas, piensa por ejemplo en el terciopelo. El diccionario de la RAE observa que éste es un significado en desuso, aunque el verbo *frisar* al parecer sigue usándose.

*Sacar la frisa* es peinar la tela para que se levante el pelo y se renueve su textura. Por lo tanto, en sentido figurado, también significa "sacarle a algo el máximo provecho posible".

Desconozco lo que intentan decir con sacársela "al premiado", pero en las frases que pude leer en un googleo rápido, *sacarle la frisa al piano* o *al baile* o *a la fiesta* equivaldrían a

> Sacarle brillo
>
> Sacarle lustre
>
> Aprovecharlo al máximo

Comment: Gracias, Rodrigo, me ha quedado claro. Y torpemente no se me ocurrió googlear enunciados como los que mencionas. ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

**La Frisa. ¿Alguien sabe qué significa esa expresión?**

---

La  "Frisa", posee distintas acepciones que van desde "acercarse a o estar juntos" a "rayar en" figurativamente algo "frisa en la estupidez". Frisar es una tela en general, un tejido de seda en particular, sacar el pelo al paño o a la bayeta, levantar y retorcer los pelitos de algunos tejidos de lana por el envés. Refregar, confrontar, congeniar...

Adolfo Bioy Casares era un escritor de culto es su país y prácticamente un desconocido en España hasta 1990, cuando se le concede el "Premio Cervantes", teniendo ya 76 años. Este hecho fue precisamente el que le inspiró para presentar uno de sus cuentos con rasgos burlescos y de caricatura, así en uno de estos cuentos "El caso de los viejitos voladores", uno de los que componen "Una magia modesta", el protagonista es un anciano que narra como es premiado de forma reiterada, convirtiéndose en una crítica general de aquellos que no valoran lo que tienen o de aquello que se hace en otras etapas de la vida.

---

*El cuento termina*...

– A mí puede decirme cualquier cosa.

–Bueno, se lo digo: ya me dieron cinco o seis premios. Si continúan con este ritmo ¿usted cree que voy a sobrevivir?. Desde ya le participo que no. ¿**Usted sabe cómo le sacan la frisa al premiado**? Creo que no me quedan fuerzas para aguantar otro premio.

El cuento acaba con esta mezcla de incredulidad y de sarcasmo.

Como hemos indicado más arriba, cuando se "Frisa" se intenta sacar el pelo al paño, se intentan levantar, retorcer, sacar todas las pelotitas y pelusas que pueden acumularse en la tela para dejarla totalmente lisa, limpia y parecer como nueva. Por tanto, también es restregar, frotar al máximo hasta que se le saca el brillo o el antiguo color original que había por debajo. Sin embargo este "sacar la pelusa", es distinto al que comentas "tener pelusa" y no tiene nada que ver, más bien lo contrario no son celos, es admiración, es sacar los colores, es ponerse colorado por tanto gusto y complacencia. Así, "Sacar la Frisa" es lo mismo que "Sacar la Pelusa", una expresión argentina que se refiere a hacer algo de forma brillante o sacar un brillo figurado de algo o alguien. En este caso "Sacar la Frisa", es frotar, es sacar el jugo, exprimir al máximo, es sacar ese brillo a través de todos los halagos, cumplidos, agasajo, mimos, adulaciones, conferencias y festejos que se organizan alrededor de la figura del "premiado", por la "brillantez de su obra" y que este tiene que "aguantar", en este caso a una determinada edad, cuando las fuerzas ya flaquean y ya no esta para esos trotes o el alternar socialmente con tantas personas. Son todas estas ceremonias las que van a matar a este pobre escritor de seguir así...."*Creo que no me quedan fuerzas para aguantar otro premio*". Espero te haya ayudado.

Comment: Gracias, Diego por tu detallada respuesta y la dedicación que pusiste en ella. La necesitaba para hacer preguntas de evaluación escolar sobre el cuento y he pensado incluir tu respuesta para hacer también preguntas sobre ella. ¿Estás de acuerdo? ¡Saludos!

Comment: No hay problema Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

En el contexto, tiene sentido lo de "sacar partido o provecho". En Chile diríamos "sacar el jugo".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/24811)